# In Typescript how to get the generic return type of a method on a class instantiated in a factory(ish) function

Tags: typescript, generics, types

In the example code below, TypeScript can't infer the generic type `U` in the `fooBar` function and as a result the return type of `fooRef.doIt()` is `unknown`. Why is that and what do I need to modify in order to get the proper return type?

```
interface Foo<T> {
  foo(): T;
}

class Bar implements Foo<string> {
  foo(): string {
    return 'Bar';
  }
}

class Baz implements Foo<number> {
  foo(): number {
    return 43;
  }
}

class FooRef<T extends Foo<U>, U> {
  constructor(private instance: T) {}

  doIt() {
    return this.instance.foo();
  }
}

function fooBar<T extends Foo<U>, U>(foo: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
  return new FooRef(new foo());
}

const barRef = fooBar(Bar);
barRef.doIt(); // unknown, expected string

const bazRef = fooBar(Baz);
bazRef.doIt(); // unknown, expected number
```

Comment: I struggled with coming up with a title that accurately described my question. If you have suggestions for a better one, please let me know.

Comment: Given this example code, I would eliminate your `T` and only use `U` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wv8GMN).  If for some reason you need `T` instead, I would eliminate `U` and rewrite it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wy56gW) (and use something like `ReturnType<T["foo"]>` or `T extends Foo<infer U> ? U : never` to compute `U` from `T`).  If either of those works for you I'll be happy to write it up with an answer.  Let me know which, if any, you want to see here.  If neither, please elaborate on what's missing.

Comment: @jcalz Brilliant! I do need to know the type of the concrete class extending Foo (I should have made `instance` public) so your second option should work. If you go ahead and write up an answer showing examples using `ReturnType` and `infer` that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer was inspired by @jcalz's suggestion in the comments. I wasn't able to make it work using `infer`, as he suggested, but his suggestion using `ReturnType` works as intended and this is what I use here.

```
interface Foo<T> {
    foo(): T;
}

class Bar implements Foo<string> {
    foo(): string {
        return 'Bar';
    }
}

class Baz implements Foo<number> {
    foo(): number {
        return 43;
    }
}

class FooRef<T extends Foo<U>, U = ReturnType<T["foo"]>> {
    constructor(public instance: T) { }

    doIt(): U {
        return this.instance.foo();
    }
}

function fooBar<T extends Foo<any>>(foo: new (...args: any[]) => T) {
    return new FooRef(new foo());
}

const barRef = fooBar(Bar);
barRef.instance // (property) FooRef<Bar, string>.instance: Bar
console.log(barRef.doIt().toUpperCase()); // "BAR"

const bazRef = fooBar(Baz);
bazRef.instance // (property) FooRef<Baz, number>.instance: Baz 
console.log(bazRef.doIt().toFixed(2)) // "43.00"
```